# WP Alchemy - stripping my paragraph tags from textarea metaboxes

Tags: metabox, tinymce, wpalchemy

I cant seem to get my custom Metaboxes to display paragraphs. Here is my code:

**page.php**

```
<?php // Custom Excerpt
$custom_metabox = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_custom_meta',TRUE); 
  if($custom_metabox['child-subexcerpt']!=false) {
    echo $custom_metabox['child-subexcerpt'];
  } ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
// Custom Meta Box 
define('_TEMPLATEURL', WP_CONTENT_URL . '/' . stristr(TEMPLATEPATH, 'themes'));

include_once 'assets/custom/MetaBox.php';
include_once 'assets/custom/MediaAccess.php';

// include css to style the custom meta boxes, this should be a global
// stylesheet used by all similar meta boxes
if (is_admin()) 
{
    wp_enqueue_style('custom_meta_css', _TEMPLATEURL . '/assets/custom/meta.css');
}
$wpalchemy_media_access = new WPAlchemy_MediaAccess();
$custom_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_custom_meta', // underscore prefix hides fields from the custom fields area
    'title' => 'Template Specific Attributes',
    'types' => array('page'),
    'template' => TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/custom/mb-pages.php',
));
```

**meta.php**

```
<?php $mb->the_field('child-subexcerpt'); ?>
  <label>Excerpt:</label>
  <textarea cols="20" rows="20" class="temp_options_desc" name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>"><?php $mb->the_value(); ?></textarea>
```

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by installing the "Advanced Tinymce" plugin.

I found that when my main rich text editor was switched to "text" that the other editors displayed differently and outputted the html.

Odd!

Answer (score 0):

I have traditionally solved this problem by duplicating `the_content` and its default, formatting filters. This avoids plugins that hook into `the_content` to add things.

Add to your theme's functions.php or wherever you are implementing WP Alchemy from.

```
//recreate the default filters on the_content
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wptexturize'        );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_chars'      );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wpautop'            );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

Then apply the new `meta_content` filter to your desired content.

```
echo apply_filters( 'meta_content', $your_content );
```